# Iframe details operation?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I need to know when the iframe generate his contents, because i need to access his body whit javascript but, sometimes, and i don't know why, the body object doesn't exist ... I often play with the iframe, i insert it in an object and i recover it to insert it into another object and when i do this, the body object disapear and i don't know why :/ i think that the iframe object is a little complexe to use...

Here is a portion of my code :

```
field("fuse")._elt.onclick = function(oEvent){
            var src=oEvent.srcElement.offsetParent.offsetParent.parentElement;
            var ed1=field(src.previousSibling.id);
            var ed2=field(src.nextSibling.id);
            debugger;
            if(ed1.getClassName() == "HTMLEditorField" && ed2.getClassName() == "HTMLEditorField"){
                var p=ed1.getParentField();
                var pp=p.getParentField();
                var ind=p._index;

                /* On retire le composant qui contient les 2 éditeurs */
 /*Here when i remove p, which contains iframes, my iframe ed1 lost his contentWindow */
                pp.removeChild(p);
                p.removeChild(ed1);

                /* On redéfinie les hauteurs et largeur de l'éditeur après l'avoir inséré à la place des 2 autres éditeurs */
                pp.insertChild(ed1,ind);
 /*And here when i insert it in an other object, ed1 recover his contentWindow and document but the body object of his document isn't created ... */
                ed1.setWidth(p.getUserAttribute("width"));
                ed1.setHeight(p.getUserAttribute("height"));

                currentEditor=ed1;

                /* Suppression de la barre d'espacement dans la liste des barres */
                lSpacerField.remove(field(src.id));
            }
        }
```

I hope that you can help me, thanks in advance.

(Sorry for my english level i'm french)

Comment: You describe a scenario, would you mind showing us this in actual code?

Comment: I've updated my post with a part of my code ^^

Answer (score 0):

Iframes are  a pain to use, You have very little control over them, Do you have any alternative that you may want to use. Coming to your question, I think you can use something like below, just pseudocode:

```
function getContentFromIframe(iFrameName)
{

    var myIFrame = document.getElementById(iFrameName);
    var content = myIFrame.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;

    //Do whatever you need with the content    

}
```

Comment: yeah i know that, but the body object is not recreated when i reinsert my iframe so i can't update the content with my backup :/

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my problem, it seems to be "designMode" javascript attribute which cause the body instability, so instead of "designMode" i have used the "contentEditable" body attribute  to make my iframe editable and all works good !